# How can I find out the coefficient of a polynomial by knowing certain coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra

What's the method of finding the coefficient of the following polynomial using the information given in the graph?

$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

I know that the first line of my matrix would look like this:
$\begin{smallmatrix} (0&0&0&1 |10)\\  \end{smallmatrix}$

[image: graph]
But what should I do with the other points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the 4 equations
\begin{align*}
d&=10\\
a+b+c+d&=7\\
27 a + 9 b + 3c +d&=-11\\
64 a + 16 b + 4 c + d &=-14
\end{align*}
Just solve it for $a,\dots,d$

You get the equations by using that $p(1)=a \cdot 1^3 + b\cdot 1^2 + c\cdot 1 + d$ and similiar with the others.

Comment: Well said...  +1.

Comment: Note that since the coefficient matrix is a reflected Vandermonde matrix with determinant (up to sign) $1\times3\times4\times2\times3\times1=72$, you know beforehand that there is going to be a unique solution.

Comment: polynominterpolation is unique if the points given are not the same, as $0,1,3,4$ are pairwise diffent, that is always given. And as you always have vandermonde matrices at polynominterpolation it is not so surprising, I didn't mention it, because i think it would confuse the OP more than it would help